# Linq-to-SQL : fetch data like SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have a query which returns 200000 records (5 joins). In SQL Server Management Studio, the query executed in 6 min, but data started to display after 8 sec.

How to get this way of fetching data in Linq-to-SQL? I set up command timeout to 3 min but have command timeout exception. Execution plan doesn't show any suspicious actions.

Comment: You could use paging, unless there's a specific reason why you need 200,000 records displayed on a single page?

Comment: it is export data feature

Comment: Depending on the query, using a stored procedure might be quicker.